# AzureAD SSO Android MsalException - BrowserTabActivity is missing when it is clearly in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, gradle, azure-active-directory, android-manifest, azure-ad-msal

For a quick background, my Android project has more than 100 `productFlavors` in the `app/build.gradle` file. Each `productFlavor` is a distinct app, with a different package name, different resources, and different Office SSO information. I inject the host, path and scheme values into the manifest from the `app/build.gradle` file like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="${hostName}"
                    android:path="${pathName}"
                    android:scheme="${schemeName}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and

```
AppName {  
            applicationId 'xxx.xxx.packagename'
            manifestPlaceholders = [schemeName: "msauth", hostName: "xxx.xxx.packagename", pathName: "/path"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.AppName
        }
```

My `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are both 31; this happens to all Android devices and all OS versions I've tested; I'm using gradle version 7.1.1; and this is what I have for the relevant dependencies in `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:2.+'
implementation 'com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:1.5.+'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases' }

    google()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MicrosoftDeviceSDK/DuoSDK-Public/_packaging/Duo-SDK-Feed/maven/v1'
    }
    maven {
        name "vsts-maven-adal-android"
        url "https://identitydivision.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/AndroidADAL/maven/v1"
        credentials {
            username System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_USERNAME") != null ? System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_USERNAME") : project.findProperty("vstsUsername")
            password System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_ACCESSTOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_ACCESSTOKEN") : project.findProperty("vstsMavenAccessToken")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run any of the variants in bundle form, except for the `defaultConfig`, I get the error in the title. When I run these apps in APK form, SSO works fine. It's only when I run the app using the bundle that I get the BrowserTabActivity is missing `MsalException`.

I used [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android) to configure Office SSO for the apps.

To reproduce this issue, configure your `app/build.gradle` file to use the `productFlavor` and `manifestPlaceholder` injection pattern. Then, in Android Studio for example, run the app by deploying the APK from the app bundle, by clicking Run -> Edit Configurations... -> General -> Installation Options -> Deploy -> APK from app bundle and then run the app.

The key to this issue is probably in the difference between APK packaging and bundle packaging. Please let me know how I can fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if any of these can help you in resolving the issue.

- Please double-check that the package name is right. Your package name serves as a unique identification for your application.
- To eliminate run-time exceptions or at the very least give msal exceptions, try upgrading to the most recent msal versions.
- To support redirection throughout the authorization code grant flow, make sure the redirect uri is registered in the app configuration (msal config.json) as well as in AndroidManifest.xml.
- Question if the user who is authenticating has a browser enabled on their device. Recommend using a browser that supports custom tabs. To support browsers similar to this, see if ParentActivity is required in the msal exception for Android.
- If everything is set up correctly, there may be a conflict with the device you're using, and we're not sure which msal package is compatible with which device. So give the most recent version a shot. Check [msal android tested browsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-android-single-sign-on#browser-selection-heuristic)

Also please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-xamarin-android-considerations).